# JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT - Need to get value from <Select> on jquery dialog using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-dialog

I have a JQUERY based dialog box, which has a 'select' on it. When I click the button, I need to get hold of the select option value.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
            $( "#dialog-select" ).dialog({
                resizable: true,
                height:250,
                width:450,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {

                        var priority = $('#dialog-select')
                        .find('select[name="priority"]');
                        var priorityString = JSON.stringify(priority);

                        alert('priorityString : ' + priorityString);

                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        return true;                        
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

The HTML for the dialog is written in JavaScript. This is below:

```
            $('#dialog-select').html('<p><span>Please select</span></p>'+
                            '<table>'+
                                '<tbody>'+
                                    '<tr>'+
                                        '<td align="left"><font size="1" color="red">*</font></td>'+
                                        '<td align="left"><label>New Priority</label></td>'+
                                        '<td>'+
                                            '<select name="priority">'+
                                                '<option value = "default">Please select...</option>'+
                                                '<option value = "h">High</option>'+
                                                '<option value = "m">Medium</option>'+
                                                '<option value = "l">Low</option>'+
                                            '</select>'+
                                        '</td>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                '</tbody>'+
                            '</table>'+
                            '<br/>');
```

What I have done above doesn't work, please help :)

Comment: If you want more specific help than my answer below you should really create an jsfiddle for us to play around with, makes it so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (on your page, given that specific html) you can only identify the select by its `Name` (without having to traverse the DOM), the quickest solution is:

```
 var selectedvalue =    $('select[name="priority"]').val();
```

I would suggest adding an ID to the dropdownlist, it will be a more efficient search. But hardly noticeable unless your page is huge, so it's more a ""good practice principle".

**Please note:**
I used ' for the jQuery selector string, and " for the name value within the selector. You could use them the other way around, but they *will have to be different*.

Answer (score 4):

Either use `$("#element").val()` for the **value** of the selected option or `$("#element option:selected").text()` for getting the **name/text** of the selected option.